# event for touchscreen on slightest touch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element hidden by default and show when a user hovers over this element with the mouse. On touchscreens, this event is only fired when the element is tapped. What Im looking for is a way to make this show **as soon as the user's finger touches that element**, I can't seem to find an event like that.

I have tried the following code:

```
//OnTouch event for about text
$('#about thumbnail').on('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).find('.mask').addClass('touch');
}).on('touchend', function(){
    $(this).find('.mask').removeClass('touch');
});
```

with no success either, I have the default Wordpress jQuery included, do I need an additional library to make my code work?  I can't find out how to do this.

thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are not developing for the latest Apple iPhone which has 3D touch you cannot detect slight and hard touches. Every touch input is considered as click. but you can try reducing the response time delay though.
use this library http://hammerjs.github.io/ it has the ability to overcome the 500ms lock in phone browsers.
If you reduce the response time it can somewhat emulate the slight touch you are asking for.

UPDATE: Here is this another library which provides more events like
tap, Single-tap, Double-tap, Hold, 2x Fingers Tap, 2x Double-tap, Swipe Drag, Rotate, Pinch, Pinch Out, Fingers
 http://quojs.tapquo.com

Comment: thanks for you input! there's a difference between aan 'tap' (finger on screen and lift finger of) and a touchstart (finger on screen) right? please see my edited question

Comment: Have you checked out the link I provided ? May be it can be of help.

Comment: @BorisKamp I forgot about this. http://quojs.tapquo.com/ It has multiple event support like tap Single-tap Double-tap Hold 2x Fingers Tap 2x Double-tap Swipe Drag Rotate Pinch Pinch Out Fingers.

Comment: Thanks! it's all taps though, that library has no examples so I cannot check if it has what I want. Did you see my link and tried in on a phone? how would you create something like that?

Comment: Thanks! Will look more into this the next few weeks somewhere, will post back if I got it done or am stuck. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to get back here but found a solution to achieve a hover effect on touch devices.

What you can do:

**1->** achieve hover effect by touching the object on a touchdevice, this hover effect stays active until you activate another hover effect. You can do this by binding 'touchstart' to any object like so:

```
$('body .archive-item').bind('touchstart', function() {});
```

I did not find a way to stop the hover as soon as your finger gets of the touchscreen with the above function.

**2->** You can bind `touchstart` and `touchend` to the above selector and have them `addClass` on `touchstart` and `removeClass` on `touchend`

```
$('body .archive-item').bind('touchstart', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
$('body .archive-item').bind('touchend', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

now you can style the `.archive-item.hover` with css to achieve a hover effect.

To avoid duplicating css to achieve the hover effect on `:hover` and the `touchstart` you can just do this:

```
.archive-item:hover,
.archive-item.hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: red;
}
```

I couldn't find anything on the web so this is what I figured out by combining some code from various snippets, what do you guys think about this?